# Django app where you can send application to authorities

Tags: django, django-models

I am currently working to write a web app where people fill out the necessary information, and apply to their mentors.

So, at this point, mentors have a model class that is pretty much like the applicant's, so that they can correct the applicant's info without affecting the applicant's original profile.

I will appreciate any helpful comments. Specifically, I am looking for:

-A similar per-exisiting django app that does more or less so I can browse the source.
-Any special Django feature that allows this that I can not aware of.
-General info on how things like these are done in general.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ad general info)

You would benefit from doing this in a single model (say `ApplicationModel`), with fields in pairs - `field_name_applicant`, `field_name_mentor`.

Then use a [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#CreateView) with its `fields` property set to only the `*_applicant` fields for the applicant to fill in the applications initially, and an [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#updateview) with its fields set to the `*_mentor` fields for the mentor to correct the applicant fields.

Have `ApplicationModel.clean()` copy all `*_applicant` field values to their `*_mentor` counterpart if the later is not set.

Now you have all your business logic in the model where it belongs; quoting a headline in the introduction of [Two Scoops of Django](https://django.2scoops.org/):

> Fat Models, Helper Modules, Thin Views, Stupid Templates

Comment: Thank you for the advice. However, in my case, one mentee can be advised by multiple mentors, kind of like college application. So, I need to have the profile duplicated to each mentor so that the original data of the mentee/applicant remains the way they saved. Would you have any recommendation in this situation?